# Преобразование списка списков в список словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Есть табличные данные в виде списка со структурой:

```
raw_data= [
  ['id', '1', '2', '3'],
  ['email', 'wer@gmail.com', 'er@gmail.com','as@gmail.com'],
]
```

т.е. это таблица в виде списка списков, где `raw_data[n]` это столбец (столбцов много, 62), а `raw_data[n][0]` название столбца. Нужно преобразовать это в список словарей:

```
data= [
{'id': '1', 'email': 'wer@gmail.com'},
{'id': '2', 'email': 'er@gmail.com'},
{'id': '3', 'email': 'as@gmail.com'},
]
```

Ясно, что это можно делать через вложенные циклы, т.е. для каждого `raw_data[n][i]` брать `i` элемент и добавлять в словарь.

Возможно есть какое-то более элегантное/pythonic решение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### При условии что количество элементов в каждом из дочерних списков одинаковое:

```py
from typing import List, Tuple
from pprint import pp

raw_data = [
    ['id', '1', '2', '3'],
    ['email', 'wer@gmail.com', 'er@gmail.com', 'as@gmail.com'],
    ['phone', '+000000000000', '+1111111111111', '+33333333333333']
]


def to_items(elements: list) -> List[Tuple]:
    key, *values = elements
    return [
        (key, value,)
        for value in values
    ]


p = [dict(elem) for elem in
    zip(*map(
        to_items, raw_data
    ))
]

pp(p)
```

Output

```latex
[{'id': 1, 'email': 'wer@gmail.com', 'phone': '+000000000000'},
 {'id': 2, 'email': 'er@gmail.com', 'phone': '+1111111111111'},
 {'id': 3, 'email': 'as@gmail.com', 'phone': '+33333333333333'}]
```

Comment: Мб аннотацию для возвращаемого значения добавить `def to_items(elements: list) -> list:` или def to_items(elements: list) -> list[tuple]:? :)

Answer (score 2):

Ключи заранее найдем, а значения в ходе перебора стобцов:

```
raw_data = [
    ['id', '1', '2', '3'],
    ['email', 'wer@gmail.com', 'er@gmail.com', 'as@gmail.com'],
    ['phone', '+000000000000', '+1111111111111', '+33333333333333']
]
keys = [x[0] for x in raw_data]
for j in range(1, len(raw_data[0])):
    values = [row[j] for row in raw_data]
    print(dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

Результат:

```
{'id': '1', 'email': 'wer@gmail.com', 'phone': '+000000000000'}
{'id': '2', 'email': 'er@gmail.com', 'phone': '+1111111111111'}
{'id': '3', 'email': 'as@gmail.com', 'phone': '+33333333333333'}
```

**PS.**

Если еще сразу в виде списка получать:

```
data = [
    dict(zip(keys, [row[j] for row in raw_data]))
    for j in range(1, len(raw_data[0]))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_data = [
    ['id', '1', '2', '3'],
    ['email', 'wer@gmail.com', 'er@gmail.com', 'as@gmail.com'],
    ['phone', '+000000000000', '+1111111111111', '+33333333333333']
]


raw_data = zip(*raw_data)
keys = next(raw_data)
for values in raw_data:
    print(dict(zip(keys, values)))
```